# Data frame column values and explanation

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame as below and I want to get rid of the columns which contains explanations/info about other column values, such as `A_NAME`, `B_NAME`. Also, I would like to store code-explanation pairs for later use.

For example,

```
   A_CODE      A_NAME    B_CODE      B_NAME     C_CODE     C_NAME  \
0       0      GARDEN       100   GARDENING      10000      TOOLS  
1       2        FOOD       102     LIQUIDS      10002      WATER   
2       1    CLOTHING       101        MALE      10001     SPORTS   
3       2        FOOD       102     LIQUIDS      10002      WATER  
4       0      GARDEN       100   GARDENING      10000      TOOLS   
..     ..         ...       ...         ...        ...        ...
    D_CODE          D_NAME      E_CODE               E_NAME  
0  5000000      HAND TOOLS         303               SHOVEL   
1  6000000   MINERAL WATER         505    5-LT WATER BOTTLE  
2  7000000           PANTS         302               SHORTS  
3  6000000   MINERAL WATER         505    1-LT WATER BOTTLE 
4  5000000      HAND TOOLS         303                  AXE  
..     ...             ...         ...                  ...
```

I want to store only `*_CODE` columns in the data frame and code-name pairs in other variables. I need code-name pairs for each type: A,B,C,D,E. What is the best of doing this?

I need this for A :
{A:{0: GARDEN,1: CLOTHING,2: FOOD}}

and for B :
{B:{100: GARDENING,101: MALE,102: LIQUIDS}}

For example if I want to know what 100 means for B, B(100), it should give me "GARDENING".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First save the name-code columns in a new dataframe with:

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
for i in range(0, len(cols), 2):
    try:
        codes_df = codes_df.append(df[[cols[i], cols[i+1]]].rename({cols[i]: 'code', cols[i+1]: 'name'}, axis=1).assign(source=cols[i))
    except NameError:
        codes_df = df[[cols[i], cols[i+1]]].rename({cols[i]: 'code', cols[i+1]: 'name'}, axis=1).assign(source=cols[i])
```

Then you can leave just the codes columns with:

```
df = df[[col for col in cols if 'CODE' in col]]
```

However, the first part will work only if the columns are arranged just like you posted. Otherwise, you would need to use checks on column names.

Comment: In the result I need to see which code is from which column, A,B,C,D,E. Because code 101 can mean MALE for B, and it can also mean PENCIL for E.

Comment: @elks I added an `assign` order that adds a column named "source" that would have the source column name.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the name columns and store the pairs in a dict. But I don't know why you dont want to keep the combinations in a DataFrame.

```
names = {}
for c in df.columns:
    if 'NAME' in c:
        names[c] = list(zip(df[c[:-4]+'CODE'], df[c].values))
        df.drop(c,axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simply way to keep only code columns:

```
df2 = df[(lambda column: df.filter(like='_CODE').columns)]
```

I used another dataframe, named df2, to not lose original data.

Than, you can store the codes in a variable named codes, and place the values in it:

```
codes = []

for i in range(len(df.columns)-1):
        pairs = df.iloc[:,i:i+2].apply(lambda row: ','.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
        codes.append(pairs)
```

Notice it will keep pretty much the structure of the original dataframe, if you print it, you will see, something like:

```
        [0      0,GARDEN
        1        2,FOOD
        2    1,CLOTHING
        3        2,FOOD
        4      0,GARDEN
        dtype: object, 
        0      0,GARDEN
        1        2,FOOD
        2    1,CLOTHING
        3        2,FOOD
        4      0,GARDEN
        dtype: object, 
        .
        .
        .
```

If you want a neat list with unique values, import numpy and do:

```
np.unique(codes)
```

The result is:

```
array(['0,GARDEN', '1,CLOTHING', '100,GARDENING', '10000,TOOLS',
        '10001,SPORTS', '10002,WATER', '101,MALE', '102,LIQUIDS', '2,FOOD',
        'CLOTHING,101', 'FOOD,102', 'GARDEN,100', 'GARDENING,10000',
        'LIQUIDS,10002', 'MALE,10001'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't state it correctly, B_CODE and E_CODE can include same values.

Comment: The code I gave you works with the dataframe as it is, it doesn't drop any column. Try it and you will see. And with the np.unique I've just got all the distinct combinations for code and code_name.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I worked only with columns A,B,C, but the solution applies to the entire dataframe.

Comment: Your code doesn't specify the columns. When I look for the name of 101 it will give me "MALE" but for the column "E_CODE" 101 should give me "PENCIL" e.g. 101 has multiple pairs for multiple columns. (B,101, MALE), (E,101, PENCIL), etc.

Comment: The problem is that code accepts multiple values. The print you provided doesn't show this inconsistency. 
It's not a code issue, it's more like a data problem. Who decides 101 is Male or Pencil?As you state they're both.

Comment: Anyway, try my code with your data. When you execute np.unique(codes) it will give you all unique combinations. Including (101,'Male') and (101,'Pencil')